# Facebook UiLifeCycleHelper in multiple activities

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to implement facebook sdk in my app. I have three activities.
Main Activity(for facebook login) which works well with UiLifeCycleHelper.

```
private UiLifecycleHelper uiHelper;
    private Session.StatusCallback statusCallback = new Session.StatusCallback() {
        @Override
        public void call(Session session, SessionState state,
                Exception exception) {
            onSessionStateChange(session, state, exception);
        }
    };

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    uiHelper = new UiLifecycleHelper(this, statusCallback);
    uiHelper.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    // For scenarios where the main activity is launched and user
    // session is not null, the session state change notification
    // may not be triggered. Trigger it if it's open/closed.
    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
    if (session != null && (session.isOpened() || session.isClosed())) {
        onSessionStateChange(session, session.getState(), null);
    }
    uiHelper.onResume();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    uiHelper.onPause();
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    uiHelper.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    uiHelper.onDestroy();
}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
    Session.saveSession(session, outState);
    uiHelper.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}

private void onSessionStateChange(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
    if (state.isOpened()) {
        Log.i(Consts.TAG, "Logged in...");
        setCookies();
    } else if (state.isClosed()) {
        Log.i(Consts.TAG, "Logged out...");
    }
}
```

But I have other two activities StepOneActivity and StepTwoActivity which also needs to integrate facebook sdk. So do i have to use the same UiLifeCycleHelper instance in these activities. Please tell me how do i implement uilifecyclehelper in StepOneActivity and StepTwoActivity which are launched as `startActivity(new Intent(this,StepOneActivity.class));` from MainActivity. I have to post a text from StepOneActivity and invite friends from StepTwoActivity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a FacebookActivity thats a parent class of all of those Activities that require Facebook implementation

From the parent activity you would call all the lifecycle methods and on all of those three activitys extend from the FacebookActivity

That way you have to write those lifecycle methods once, and if you ever need another Activity with FB implementation, just make it extend from FacebookActivity

Here's a beautiful graph created in Paint
[image: Graph]